# WiFi active and connection ok, but no eth0 or wlan0

Tags: networking, fedora, wifi, ifconfig

I'm on Fedora, and trying to find my local IP address, so I ran `ifconfig -a` and got back the following:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 96855  bytes 3248510 (3.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 96855  bytes 3248510 (3.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p3p1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f0:bf:97:1c:06:47  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.16  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::6680:99ff:fe24:2b70  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 64:80:99:24:2b:70  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6320917  bytes 7972484964 (7.4 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2394386  bytes 343585425 (327.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It seems that the correct info is under `wlp2s0` but firstly, I'm not sure what these three are, and secondly, I'm used to seeing `eth0` and/or `wlan0` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Recent Fedora releases use systemd and the new style Predictable Network Interface Names.

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

You can override them if you really want with udev rules, but it's probably worth the effort to just get used to the new names - they won't change again, that's their point.